# I've an undirected NetworkX graph and want to find all neighbors of node_a that are also neighbors of node_b

Tags: python, networkx

Straightforward questions: how do I find all the neighbors in common between node_a and node_b and what's the best way to do it?

The code I have is:

```
my_node_list_a = [ ... ]
my_node_list_b = [ ... ]

for c in my_node_list_a:
    for x in nx.neighbors(G, c):
        for y in my_node_list_b:
            for h in nx.neighbors(G, y):
                 if x in y:
                    print(x)
```

This is bad code. First of all I'm having to manually populate `my_node_list_a` and `my_node_list_b` by executing `for i in G.nodes(): print(i)` and only putting in the arrays the nodes I want to run the loop against.

**EDIT**:

The title says neighbors, but I'm new to networkx so it might not be the correct term. If neighbors only means the nodes of distance 1 then yes, this is what I want.

However, I'm also interested in what nodes connect the nodes in the arrays `my_node_list_a` and `my_node_list_b` that are of greater distance than 1, so if anyone can show me how to do that, it would be useful too (basically, to show me the path(s) between them)

**Further edit**:

I need to create a graph from my main graph `G` based on the neighbors of a selection of nodes.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @further edit: use subgraph method.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler - will this only select the shared neighbors of the selection of nodes I pass to nx.subgraph()? It's important for me not to include all neighbors of the nodes I pass in, only the ones which are shared with the other nodes I include.

Comment: The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) has all the answers.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler - OK so the graph that this produces is rendered weird. My nodes are A -> B -> C -> D (direction is not important) or A -> C -> D, or B -> C -> D. I.e. there is always "C" before D and always either A or B connecting to a C -> D. By doing subgraph I get C -> D nodes where A or B is not connected to C. Also, there are disconnected networks of B -> C in various places too and sometimes just C on their own. These things are not desired. I specifically only want to plot the shared neighbors C between nodes [A, B, D].

Comment: I dont know what your goal is. But the subgraph method only plots the nodes including their possible connections of the subset you give the function. This is all stated in the docs I linked.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler - then this does not achieve what I want, as I tried to explain by stating 'shared neighbors' which in my case is I'm trying to only plot from G a set of nodes n's common connections C (where nodes 'n' are [A, B, D]). I think what I'm going to have to do is first find all the shared neighbors of nodes n (which is a task in and of itself!) which will give me all of C and then pass those as a set to `subgraph`. So I'm still back at my question in 'further edit' by the looks of it. I will keep digging, but thanks! (just noticed that even if I achieve this, it might break A -> B)

Comment: Given graph G = (V,E). Your aim is to find H \subset V under the condition that H = { x : (i, c) \in E} with c being the common neighbor? Edit: to clarify you only want  the nodes that are the common neighbor or the entire subnet, or only the nodes that share a neighbor..?

Comment: I don't fully understand the abstraction. My graph is of vehicle (A), partial vehicle license number (B), road (C), city (D). C can be a shared road by different vehicles heading to the same destination. Some A get to D by taking a different C. Sometimes in my data I don't have A but I have B, and sometimes I have A but not B, but whichever I always have C -> D (so: A -> B -> C -> D or A -> C -> D or B -> C -> D). I only want to plot a select few (A,B) (my choosing) that share a common route C to D as other vehicles again of my choosing. Is this what the abstraction you notated represents?

Comment: Yeah that clear is up a lot. The node_boundary method shown below can help you, i.e. for your example node_boundary(AB, D), where AB is the union of A and B (since you have missing values)

Answer (score 5):

To find common neighbors between two nodes you can use the function `common_neighbors()`:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.turan_graph(6, 2)

%matplotlib inline # jupyter notebook
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)

list(nx.common_neighbors(G, 3, 5))
# [0, 1, 2]
```

[image: graph]

To find common neighbors between two sets of nodes (vertices) you can use the function `node_boundary()`:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import chain

G = nx.grid_graph(dim=[5, 5])

list_A = [(3, i) for i in range(5)]
list_B = [(1, i) for i in range(5)]
intersec = nx.node_boundary(G, list_A) & nx.node_boundary(G, list_B)
# {(2, 1), (2, 0), (2, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4)}

color = []
for i in G.nodes():
    if i in intersec:
        col = 'green'
    elif i in chain(list_A, list_B):
        col = 'red'
    else:
        col = 'pink'
    color.append(col)

%matplotlib inline
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, node_color=color, node_size=1000)
```

[image]

Comment: That function looks useful!

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it possible to build a subset of my fully connected graph `G` from a section of nodes by extracting only the connected neighbors of each?

Comment: Note: this solution does not work for directed graphs

Comment: @GlobalTraveler OP asked about undirected graph.

Comment: @uncle-junky I’ve edited my answer. You can use the function `node_boundary()`.

Comment: @MykolaZotko is it possible to plot `intersec` separately from G, e.g. `nx.draw(intersec ... )` ?

Comment: @GlobalTraveler Create the subgraph from intersec nodes and plot it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :
(I changed my answer in case you had a big graph, to avoid you going through the mass)

```
import networkx as nx

def keep_neighbors(graph, node):
    tokeep = set()
    for k, v in g[node].items():
        # print v.get('weight') == 1
        if v.get('weight') == 1:
            tokeep.add(k)
    return tokeep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = nx.Graph()
    g.add_edge('a', 'b', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('a', 'c', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('a', 'd', weight = 2)
    g.add_edge('a', 'e', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('a', 'f', weight = 1)

    g.add_edge('z', 'c', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('z', 'd', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('z', 'e', weight = 1)

    g.add_edge('k', 'c', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('k', 'd', weight = 1)
    g.add_edge('k', 'e', weight = 1)


    a = keep_neighbors(g, 'a')
    b = keep_neighbors(g, 'z')
    print(a) # set(['c', 'b', 'e', 'f'])
    print(b) # set(['c', 'e', 'd'])

    result = a & b
    print(result) # set(['c', 'e'])

    a = keep_neighbors(g, 'k')
    b = keep_neighbors(g, 'z')
    result = a & b
    print(result) # set(['c', 'e', 'd'])
```

Comment: Is the above function not appropriate for a "big graph" ? Just curious. Also - I will update my question with more information.

Comment: It is appropriate to me. But always go for the builtins, and Mykola Zolto went for it